# MAC Flooding detection

Tags: mac-address, flooding, switch

I am interested in the metrics of the attack. Is there any packet rate that can be considered a reasonable threshold to detect this attack from traffic perspective? Or this is completely connected to the limits of the hardware?

Comment: Context is very important. You want to detect ***anomalies*** in the context.

Comment: By context you mean the setup? Or the type of traffic? What I had in mind was the detection of different macs in the packets and consider a rate. For example if you see 100 different macs in traffic in less than 2 seconds (out of my mind), then trigger an alert.

Comment: I mean "what's normal and expected" for that setup, traffic types, and nodes. Setting hard metrics depends on the context. It's better to do anomaly detection from baseline.

Comment: Makes sense. If we know the number of possible system (online and systems that are offline but can go online), can we use that number as an approximation?